# Can I use jQuery to dynamically style a form after it's validated with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to add styling to certain parts of my form based on what happens in my PHP script. For example, I'd like to add a class to an input that the user fills out incorrectly that will trigger CSS rules, such as making the input's border red.

I thought I might be able to do this using jQuery at the end of my PHP script, but I haven't been successful despite writing it several different ways. I checked to make sure my new CSS styling came after the default styling too. It may also be worthwhile to mention that I'm using AJAX to validate as well, so the user stays on the registration page if the form is not filled out properly.

Here is my PHP script (jQuery is at the end):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once "_databaseHandler.php";

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $confirmPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, 
        $_POST['confirmPassword']);

    $errorEmpty = false;

    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || 
            empty($confirmPassword))
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Please fill in all fields</span>";
            $errorEmpty = true;
    }

else
{
    $sqlUsername = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE userName = '$username'";
    $resultUsername = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlUsername);
    $resultCheckUsername = mysqli_num_rows($resultUsername);

    $sqlEmail = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE userEmail = '$email'";
    $resultEmail = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlEmail);
    $resultCheckEmail = mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail);

    //Check length of username
    if (strlen($username) < 4)
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>Your username must be at least 4 
           characters long</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }

    //Check if username is taken
    else if ($resultCheckUsername > 0)
    {
        echo "<span class='form-error'>This username is already 
            taken</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    }

    //many other checks with exact same syntax using else if...

    //Insert the user into the database
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (userName, userEmail, userPassword) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

        $statement = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $sql))
        {
            echo "<span class='form-error'>Database error</span>";

            exit();
        }

        else
        {
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPassword);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            $emailSubject = "wtf";
            $emailMessage = "Hello my son";
            mail($email, $emailSubject, $emailMessage);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['register-success'] = 'You have successfully registered! Please verify your email before logging in.';

            echo
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    window.location.href='../index.php';
                </script>";

            exit();

            }
        }
    }
}

else
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}

?>

<reference path="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";

    if (errorEmpty)
    {
        $("#register-username").addClass(".input-error");
    }

</script>
```

Full context of related code:

jQuery:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#register-username").val();
        var email = $("#register-email").val();
        var password = $("#register-password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#register-confirm-password").val();
        var submit = $("#register-submit").val();

        $(".form-message").load("../shared/_registerAccount.php", {

            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            submit: submit

        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<?php 
    include "shared/_header.php"; 
?>
<div class="wrapper-register">
    <div id="register-account">
        <div class="register-title">
            <h2>REGISTER ACCOUNT</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="shared/_registerAccount.php" method="post">
            <div class="register-input">
                <input id="register-username" type="text" name="username" 
                    maxlength="16" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="register-input">
                <input id="register-email" type="text" name="email" 
                    maxlength="128" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="register-input">
                <input id="register-password" type="password" name="password" 
                    maxlength="128" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="register-input">
                <input id="register-confirm-password" type="password" 
                    name="confirmPassword" maxlength="128" 
                    placeholder="Confirm Password" /> 
            </div> 
            <input id="register-submit" type="submit" name="submit" 
                    value="SIGN UP" class="register-button" /> 
        </form>
        <p class="form-message"></p>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php include "shared/_footer.php" ?>
    <script src="javascript/register.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you DOM has the ID and CSS has the class defined, following should do:

`$("#register-username").addClass("input-error");`

Comment: You don't show where you're generating the actual username input. Why not add the error class to that when you create it, instead of relying on jQuery to add it after the fact?

Comment: I have double checked and this code still does not work. In fact I have tried writing it several different ways, and unfortunately none have changed any styling.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the entire context of my question with related code.

Comment: @Dalsia There can be following issues when CSS is not being applied.
1. You have not included the CSS file (I don't see the file inclusion in your code)
2. You are applying it on an undefined ID or the class doesn't exist (Both of them can't be verified from your provided code).
3. The class name you are applying is wrong (In your case, you are applying '.input-error' if your class name starts with a '.', you need to escape it.)

Comment: Thank you, escaping the character was necessary. I am pretty new to web development, so I have found myself forgetting to do that on occasion.

Comment: Ideally, you should avoid using '.' in the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be following issues when CSS is not being applied"

1. You have not included the CSS file (I don't see the file inclusion in your code)
2. You are applying it on an undefined ID or the class doesn't exist (Both of them can't be verified from your provided code).
3. The class name you are applying is wrong (In your case, you are applying '.input-error' if your class name starts with a '.', you need to escape it.)